# Why is this cast to bool required?

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, standard-library

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename Predicate>
inline InputIterator
find_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred, input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (first != last && !bool(pred(*first)))
         ++first;

    return first;
}
```

I bumped into [this snippet](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/libstdc++/api/a01462_source.html) in the source code of the implementation of the C++ standard library shipped with GCC 4.7.0. This is the specialization of `find_if` for an input iterator. I cleaned the leading underscores to make it more readable.

Why did they use a `bool` cast on the predicate?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The reason is that just writing `!pred(*first)` could result in a call to an overloaded `operator!` rather than the call to `explicit operator bool`.

It's interesting that this measure was taken for `pred`, but an overloaded `operator&&` can still be selected in the implementation provided. `first != last` would need to be changed to `bool(first != last)` to also prevent this overload.

Comment: I think that if `operator&&` was overloaded, the behavior would have been undefined because of dereferencing the end iterator in the last iteration (absence of short-circuit). So perhaps the implementation is free to ignore this issue.

Comment: Why doesn't it say `static_cast<bool>` though? Why a forced cast?

Comment: @Mehrdad They do the same thing in this context because `reinterpret_cast` is never chosen. (And the GCC source is all just 80 columns wide.)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: but doesn't that mean && shouldn't be used in the first place?

Comment: @Mehrdad i don't have any idea about the question, I did only throw in some guess without any education

Answer (score 12):

The standard requires only that the predicate be usable in
a context where it can convert to a `bool`.  Presumably,
a "predicate" object could have an `operator bool` function,
which did the right thing, and an `operator!` function which did
something totally unrelated.  (Of course, that would be horrible
design, but the standard requires the library to work as
specified, regardless of how bad the user code is.)  So g++
converts to `bool`, and then uses `!` on the result of that
conversion (where only the build-in operator can apply).

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ Standard there is written relative to the predicate that

> In other words, if an algorithm takes Predicate pred as its argument
>   and first as its iterator argument, it should work correctly in the
>   construct pred(*first) contextually converted to bool

The words "contextually converted to bool" means that if even a class defines a conversion function that converts an object of the class to bool as an explicit operator it shall be applied. Consider an example of a contextual conversion to bool

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   explicit operator bool () const { return true; }
};

int main()
{
   if ( A() ) 
   {
      std::cout << "Here is a contextual conversion to bool" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

So in context of the C++ Standard quote I do not see any sense in writing expression

```
first != last && !bool( pred(*first ) )
```

It would be enough to write

```
first != last && !pred(*first )
```

Here pred is contextually converted to bool.

Comment: It is contextually converted to "bool", which is a user defined conversion. But as someone else says in a comment, if there is an `operator!`, it would be preferred. Which seems to be an excellent remark.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb  Then there is a problem. If a class does not define a conversion operator to bool but defines operator ! then the original condition will issue an error. So some realization will be compiled with operator ! while others will not.